# Call to GetPrivateProfileString on kernel32 using Python C-types

Tags: python

I try to use GetPrivateProfileString to edit ini files.It work on vb, so I try to put it in python.

```
from ctypes import *
def GetINIKey2(inipath,Content,itemname):
  kernel32 = windll.LoadLibrary("kernel32.dll")
  GetPrivateProfileString = kernel32.GetPrivateProfileStringA
  returnstring = c_wchar_p("")
  lpApplicationName = c_wchar_p(Content)
  lpKeyName = c_wchar_p(itemname)
  lpDefault = c_wchar_p('defalut')
  lpReturnedString = returnstring
  nSize = c_int(256)
  lpFileName = c_wchar_p(inipath)

  returnval = GetPrivateProfileString(byref(lpApplicationName),byref(lpKeyName),byref(lpDefault),byref(lpReturnedString),byref(nSize),byref(lpFileName))

  print(returnval)
  print(returnstring.value)
```

GetINIKey2("C:\test.ini","server","servername")

Follow is the ini file：

```
[server]
servername = 192.168.11.1
serverport = 8000
```

The returnstring.value should be "192.168.11.1", but it always be "default" which is lpDefault's value. What wrong with the code?

Answer (score -1):

This code Works:

```
def GetINIKey2(inipath,Content,itemname):
    kernel32 = windll.LoadLibrary("kernel32.dll")
    GetPrivateProfileString = kernel32.GetPrivateProfileStringW
    returnstring = c_wchar_p(""*4096)
    lpApplicationName = c_wchar_p(Content)
    lpKeyName = c_wchar_p(itemname)
    lpDefault = c_wchar_p('default')
    lpReturnedString = returnstring
    nSize = 4096
    lpFileName = c_wchar_p(inipath)
    ret=GetPrivateProfileString(lpApplicationName,lpKeyName,lpDefault,lpReturnedString,nSize,lpFileName)
    #print ("Return Error=",ret)
    return returnstring.value
```

Comment: This code may work, but how does that answer the original question? What's wrong with OP's code?